# Why is the meteor twitter bootstrap package an old version and not version 3?

Tags: meteor

Although I have a good understanding of NPM and bower to include packages in web projects, I would expect from meteor, which has a very own packaging logic, that core packages are kept up to date?
Meteor = make things easy, right? I struggled for a few hours, why meteor was not recognizing col-md-6 until I figured out it doesn't have version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it has version 3 , you can add that package using

meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3 
from meteor 0.9 version and above for more check here
    (https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-bootstrap-3)!

Answer (score 0):

Meteor shipped with several packages as "core" when it was still pre-1.0. That was when no useful packaging system was available, so the folks behind Meteor were kind enough to get developers a quick start with providing several packages.

Now that we are post 1.0 they have decided to focus their energy on developing Meteor, and not bringing in packages that can easily maintained by the community. The packaging system is available and well documented so that MDG can refrain from shipping (and maintaining!) packages that are not essential for the Meteor platform.

While I personally would have liked to see each and every package I'd need in my projects to be part of the officially maintained core, it is simply not feasible. To avoid confusion, the bootstrap package is about to vanish from meteor core soon, as you can see from the [History.md for the next version](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md)

> Some packages are no longer released as part of the core release process: amplify, backbone, bootstrap, d3, jquery-history, and jquery-layout.

Answer (score 0):

You've to have in consideration that Twitter (the company in charge of the project) isn't the official owner of the package in Atmosphere, It's a community package and if you don't like: you don't use it. That's pretty much how it works, I've had my dose of problems with atmosphere  packages, now: I simply read most of the code before using a package. You can easily spot obvious mistakes/behaviours just by reading some lines.